# How to override default behaviour of RequestParam?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I got a Rest API and I don't want to force clients to send request params.I got nearly 400 api methods and I don't want to set all parameters to "required = false"

I want to override default behaviour of Spring RequestParam. I want to set default value of "required" property of RequestParam interface to "false".

Is there any way to override it? If I can't or its not a best practice, Is there any way to solve above problem.

Comment: you can set default values for all `@RequestParam`.

Comment: You cannot change the default value, unless you build your own Spring version which has this set to `false`, or extend/replace the `HttpMethodArgumentHandler` that handles the `@RequestParam`. Also setting it to `false` might not be the solution you want, those request parameters are there for a reason...

Answer (score 2):

As was said above - you cannot change the default value.

Some possible ways to solve your problem:

- mark parameter as optional:

````
@RequestMapping(...)
public String url(@RequestParam("key") Optional<String> keyValue```){
}
````

or

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public String url(@RequestParam("key") @Nullable String keyValue){
}
```

(any annotation with "Nullable" name part, i.e. javax.annotation.Nullable)

- don't use RequestParam annotation at all - instead of it use Pojo classes for parameters binding:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public String url(PojoRequestParameters parameters) {
}

//...

public class PojoRequestParameters {
        private String key;

        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public void setKey(String key) {
            this.key = key;
        }
    }
```

- write (and register) your own annotation and use it instead of RequestParam (it's not possible to create alias for RequestParam annotation)
- change annotation value at runtime (crazy and could not work for method annotation), something like this: https://www.baeldung.com/java-reflection-change-annotation-params